# "Resources are not supported in serialized data." when using FOSRestBundle and Paginator

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, jmsserializerbundle

I am setting up a REST service for my website with the FOSRestBundle and JMSSerializerBundle.

I made a custom method on a entity repository which returns a Paginator object. The method works great when I use it on the normal website, but when I want to use the method with the REST route, this error is thrown (XML or JSON output throws the same error) :

> "Resources are not supported in serialized data."

I really don't know where to search since the error isn't very explicit to me.

Here's my AdsRestController.php :

```
<?php

namespace MyProject\MainBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\View;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\Get;


class AdsRestController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @View
     * @Get("/ads/list/all/{page}", requirements={"page" = "\id+"}, defaults={"page" = 1})
     */
    public function getAdsListAllAction($page) {

        $theAds = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MyProjectMainBundle:Ads')->getAds($page);

        return $theAds;
    }
}
```

and my AdsRepository.php :

```
<?php

namespace MyProject\MainBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator;

class AdsRepository extends EntityRepository
{

    public function getAds($page=1, $maxPerPage=10)
    {
            $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
                ->orderBy('a.date', $order)
            ;

        $query->getQuery();

        $query
            ->setFirstResult(($page-1) * $maxPerPage)
            ->setMaxResults($maxPerPage)
        ;

        return new Paginator($query, true);
    }
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated !

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `iterator_to_array` to convert iterator of your paginator into array :

```
return iterator_to_array($theAds->getIterator());
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert result manually to an array by using getAds()->toArray() in your rest controller.

already answered here, use the search!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's what I did first. But the toArray() method doesn't exist !

Comment: I get the error : ' Attempted to call method "toArray" on class "Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator '

Comment: Sorry I did not test it. Iterate over the pagination object an manually built the array. 
foreach ($paginator as $entry) {
    $result[] = $entry;
} return $result

Comment: Yes that works of course. But isn't there any other - not dirty - solution ? Thanks again for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the ->getIterator() method available on Paginator objects.
See https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/Pagination/Paginator.php

Answer (score 0):

If you use `iterator_to_array`, it will convert the result array to a single object. It is better to fetch them to an array and then serialize it.

```
 $var = [];
        foreach ($records as $rec){
            array_push($var, $rec);
        }

        $res = $this->get('jms_serializer')->serialize($var, 'json');
        return new JsonResponse(json_decode($res));
```