# Resources are not supported in serialized data

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, orm

**Hello everyone m working on a project there is a bundle CustomerBundle when i call a function following errors are display can anyone tell me why this error coccured..**

> message": "Resources are not supported in serialized data. Path:
>   Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler -> Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Logger ->
>   Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\FilesystemAdapter ->
>   Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\TraceableAdapter ->
>   Symfony\Component\Cache\DoctrineProvider ->
>   Doctrine\Common\Annotations\CachedReader ->
>   Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver ->
>   Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\Driver\MappingDriverChain ->
>   Doctrine\ORM\Configuration -> Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager ->
>   CustomerBundle\Repository\CustomerRepository",
>                   "class": "JMS\Serializer\Exception\RuntimeException",

**this is my Customer entity page**

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="CompanyBundle\Entity\Company", inversedBy="company_customer")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="company_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $companyId;


/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="created_time", type="datetimetz")
 */
private $createdTime;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="modified_time", type="datetime")
 */
private $modifiedTime;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="SalesBundle\Entity\SalesAccount", mappedBy="customerId" )
 */
private $sales_customer_id;
```

**CustomerApiController controller**

```
namespace CustomerBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations as Rest;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\FOSRestController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use FOS\RestBundle\View\View;
use CustomerBundle\Entity\Customer;

class CustomerapiController extends FOSRestController
{
    /**
     * @Rest\Post("/api/customer")
     */
    public function customerAction(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Customer::class);
        $data->find(1);
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28389046/resources-are-not-supported-in-serialized-data-when-using-fosrestbundle-and-p). Similar problem can be solved in the same way.

Write a custom repository function and do the following instead of your "find(1)" :

```
public function findFirstElement()
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('e');

    $qb->where('e.id = 1');

    return $qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
}
```

Comment: `[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "firstName": "tata ",
        "lastName": "steel",
        "createdTime": "2017-08-07T03:05:08+00:00",
        "modifiedTime": "-0001-11-30T00:00:00+00:00"
    }
]`                             it worked but there is 2 more field office_id,and company_id that is not fetched

Comment: Yes indeed. Have a look at JMS Annotations, you will find all your need.